# Tolerance circle with a radius

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have a code simulating Arm movement in hand . so at after every unit of time i determine position of arm and calculate the simple distance between arm position and target . plus when the arm reaches in a tolerance circle with some radius value k , one can say arm almost reached the target .. my problem is how to verify whether arm reached in tolerance circle
the following is the code which is very simple

```
tolerance_radius = 0.3 
d = norm(cur_pos[0] - pos_tar[0]) #distance between arm and target array
```

this is what i have tried

```
if abs(d) <tolerance_radius :
    #almost touched
else:
    #calculate new position
```

is there any other way for this specific case that can create the whole tolerance circle actually and then determine whether the arm reached in the circle or not ?

Answer (score 1):

If the distance from the hand to the target is less than tolerance_radius, then True, else False:

```
if math.hypot(target.x - arm.x, target.y - arm.y) < tolerance_radius:
  return True
else
  return False
```